# Excel set my cell's color based on value in Column B when my cell's value matches Column A

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Two Excel worksheets

One worksheet is infant mortality rates by state:
a - State name;
b - Rate number

Second is state color - red or blue:
a - State name;
b - Color

Need to match worksheet 1 a to worksheet 2 a and color worksheet 1 row based on worksheet 2's b value

Comment: This is definitely doable, however it'd be really helpful if you could post screenshots of each of the worksheets please. That way, we can provide guidance/formulas that directly refer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Select `worksheet 1` ColumnB and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'worksheet 2'!A:B,2,0)="red"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd> with red formatting, OK, OK. Reselect same column and apply another formula rule in the same way of :

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'worksheet 2'!A:B,2,0)="blue"
```

and  <kbd>Format...</kbd> with blue formatting, OK.